# Is it possible to allow only a specific computer to RDP to home network via WAN?

Tags: security, remote-desktop, wan

I have a home network with WINXP PRO/WIN2K3/WIN7 machines to which I would like to make RDP connections. I have already set up port forwarding on the router and all that good stuff, and am able to coonect from remote locations. My question is, can one force connections to the machines to come from a specific computer (preferably by checking the comp mac addr?). Would this be config at the machine level, or at the router?

If at the machine level, do I need additional sofware to accomplish this or are the tools provided with Windows sufficient?

If at the router level, will any router support this, or do I need a router with specific functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think RDP supported server authentication (as in, "you've got the right server") until v6.

I'm still not sure it allows any sort of authentication beyond user/password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When access don over internet is impossible to check MAC address (MAC always MAC of next hop Gateway) only check IP address.

In common case is possible to configure router to check IP and limit access to IP or subnet, but it depend on router firewall features.

[RDP vulnerability](http://www.google.ru/search?lr=&newwindow=1&safe=off&ei=EQSQS7zWK5iemwPc0-itAQ&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CBQQBSgA&q=rdp+vulnerability&spell=1)  mostly "Man in middle" and "Denial of Service". When you use good password chanses to be cracked not too high.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on mac addresses, this is helpful